# EFI boot option disappears after backingup or restoring efi partition with clonezilla

Tags: uefi, clonezilla

I am using clonezilla to backup and restore a laptop. It is imaged with a flavor of Debian linux (bullseye), the lay out of the disk after installing the OS is:

```
sda/
sda1 - EFI partition
sda2 - grub partition for OS
sda3 - OS lvm /home, root, swap_1, var
```

If I backup or restore sda1 (or all of sda), the EFI boot entry disappears.
The backup procedure seems to work fine. I am using `device-image` option and ssh the results to another computer. The restore also looks fine, after applying it I can see the partition table looks fine and the image is there. The GUID in the grub.cfg file looks fine to me as well

I can boot into the OS if load gparted and select `Local operating system`. once booted I can fix the restored image by running `grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi`

Or I can I can fix it with a live cd by setting the boot order with `evibootmgr`:

```
## before
# efibootmgr 
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001
Boot0001* UEFI: NameOfUSBDrive with gparted
Boot0003* debian

## after
# efibootmgr -o 3
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003
Boot0001* UEFI: NameOfUSBDrive with gparted
Boot0003* debian
```

After that, it boots up to the install OS. I think it might be the hardware.

laptop info:
Dell Latitude 3190, UEFI boot mode, secure boot disabled

Comment: If you enter the clonezilla expert mode, can you find a parameter that might cause the problem (perhaps "-iefi")?

Comment: -iefi is not checked.